# How to read special characters from file system in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
String jsonData = Gdx.files.internal("data/" + spreadsheet + ".json").readString();
```

When try to print this String , characters such as `ö`,`ä`,`ü` , show up as `√º` and other characters not similar to original for e.g. `ü` shows up as `√º`.

How can I remedy this?

I want to serialise this later into a class instance.
Should I use some other method instead of readString?

Something else I tried - I passed the filehandle itself to the Json object to serialise, but still characters show up as some other characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I specified the charset and the problem is solved now

....`readString("UTF-8");`